# Removing the corresponding texts when the object is hit

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My problem is that I could get the texts disappear but  what i wanted is to make the text disappear when the balloons that they are on is hit. For example, i hit the first balloon that contains 'balloonText' in it, how does the code determine that it is the balloon that contains 'balloonText' is hit? Since all the balloons generated are called 'balloon'.

```
function createBalloons(a, b)
  for i = 1, a do
     for j = 1, b do

         local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 465+ (i * 30), 80 + (j * 50))
         balloonText = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+1], 495, 125)
         balloonTextt = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+2], 495, 175)
         balloonTexttt = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+3], 495, 225)
         balloonText:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonTextt:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonTexttt:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloon.name = 'balloon'
         physics.addBody(balloon)
         balloon.bodyType = 'static'
         table.insert(balloons, balloon)
         end
    end
    target.text = #balloons
end
--ball collides with balloon
function ballCollision(e)
   if (e.other.name == 'balloon') then
        e.target:removeSelf() 
        e.other:removeSelf()
        audio.play(pop)
        score.text = score.text + 50
        score.anchorX = 0
        score.anchorY = 0
        score.x = 200
        score.y = 50
        target.text = target.text - 1
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeSelf` on e.other (or e.object2) or e.target (or e.object1):

```
function ballCollision(e)
   if (e.other.name == 'balloonText') then
        e.target:removeSelf() 
        e.other:removeSelf()
```

You should not set e.target etc to nil or anything. If you used balloon:addEventListener('collision', ballCollision), you may have to use e.object1 and e.object2.

Comment: so for example the second text's condition will be like if (e.object1.name == 'balloonTextt') then ....end for the ballCollision function?

Comment: Exactly. As a side note I recommend you append 1 2 3 instead of t and tt and then what, ttt?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hope you don't mind I ask one more question, I'm stuck on how I could link balloontext 1,2 and 3 to the three balloons. As you can see on top, i generate the balloons with 1 object name 'balloon', but what if i wanted to shoot the second balloon so the balloon that holds "balloontext2" disappears? How do i link the text correspondingly to each balloons?

Comment: @user3305142 Hard to understand, it's better anyways to stick to one question. Close this one (IIUC) and ask separate question with details and example code. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code

```
  local myImage = display.newImageRect(view,"image_name.png",50,50 )
    myImage.x = _x
    myImage.y = _y
    physics.addBody( myImage )
    myImage.collision = onCollision 
    myImage:addEventListener(   "collision", myImage );
    myImage.myName="balloonText";

function onCollision(e)
   if (e.other1.name == 'balloonText') then
        e.other1:removeSelf() 
        e.other2:removeSelf()
 end
```

this code is for image you can use it for text also

Comment: what does the e.other2 remove? The second text?

Comment: second object which will collide with object named 'balloonText'